# Granting Java and file access to a trusted program

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, file-permissions

When I log into a vpn for work It always asks to grant it file access rights.  It also asks for to use or access Java (3 times).  I rust the program, can I give automatic or permanent rights to such programs?